# Paypal: Non Periodical Automatic Payment

Tags: paypal, payment, braintree, gateway, billing

In paypal I know there is currently automatic subscription that require linked card, so they can charge directly from it.

However, this only work in periodical terms (daily, weekly, etc)

I was wondering if we can make it non-periodical? (non recurring)

Lets say

- In private auction system, a user can link his paypal. When he make bid & won, charged automatically
- In ticket hunt system, a user can link his paypal. When a certain ticket slot available, that user is automatically buying in
- In hourly worker system, a user can link his paypal to hire someone. At the end of the jobs when its done (not specified upfront), charged automatically

Looking around for some time, it seems what i need is **Billing Agreement**/**Future Payment** API. However, both are deprecated. And haven't found any since then

I've also explored another gateway alternative (like braintree), but no luck.
Make me wonder if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Braintree Gateway, if available in your country and if approved for you, will have this feature.

PayPal Reference Transactions, if approved for a live PayPal business account account, gives this feature. The specific API you end up integrating may or may not be one of the deprecated ones and may or may not be publicly documented; before the API choice matters, you first need the Reference Transaction feature activated for a live PayPal business account.  PayPal can advise you on how to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with the concept of tokenization. Novalnet Payment Gateway has this tokenization feature to the merchants in some scenarios like, later booking of the order (without customer interaction), in case of periodic recurring, and for allowing the faster checkout to the end-customers (like saved Paypal details). You can check this guide (https://developer.novalnet.de/onlinepayments/reactnative)for more on this.